# How some whatsapp auto reply apps can use our own phone number to do auto reply? I want to build using PHP

Tags: api, twilio, whatsapp, auto, reply

I'm applying from Twilio to use their WhatsApp API service they are providing to build a WhatsApp auto-reply bot. But the problem here is that they want us to use the phone number they provide to us which we need to buy from them.

I tried using the URL 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567' but it just redirects to a page to send a message which I need to click 'Send' in order for it to submit our message. Besides that, we need to be able to trigger the application that a message is received from a recipient so we still need to access the API.

So how exactly is it I want to build a Whatsapp Auto Reply service to the public if Twilio provides it's own phone number only to reply. I want to reply using phone numbers that my clients register with me which is their own phone numbers.

As we know Whatsapp API is not open for public but how other Whatsapp Auto Reply apps are able to use our phone number to auto-reply to our recipients?

Would love some feedback or solutions from StackOverflow community. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently the Twilio [documentation on using numbers on WhatsApp says](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#enabling-whatsapp-with-a-twilio-number):

> Currently, we are unable to enable WhatsApp on non-Twilio numbers; support for this is coming soon and we will update these docs once available.

So this is just a current limitation and will be changed in the future.